# Format date for current locale, adding the weekday

Tags: java, android, date, string-formatting

I can format a given date and time for the current locale using this:

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(date)
```

It's important that I'm not specifying a format string here. It's the system's decision how to format the date and time, e.g. the order of the fields.

However, the "medium" date format does not include the weekday. I would like to include that by passing `DateFormat.MEDIUM or DateFormat.DAY_OF_WEEK_FIELD` (it's Kotlin), but that throws an exception saying the format is not valid. So apparently it's not valid to combine those two values. I somehow understand that (`MEDIUM` defines a specific format, and the system doesn't know where to place the weekday). But I would like to be able to say "Use the locale specific (medium) formatting, and add the weekday wherever it makes sense". Is there a way to do that?

(I'm writing the snippets without access to the real code, so please forgive any errors.)

Comment: No there isn’t. Sorry. How would the system know where it makes sense to insert the weekday?

Comment: I think I might present the formatted date and the day of week in two different fields so the user doesn’t get the impression they were supposed to be part of the same string.

Comment: @OleV.V. The same way it knows where it makes sense to place any other field. The day of week *is* supposed to be part of the same string. There exists a placeholder for it that can be used in a format string (EEEE). I just don't want to specify the format string myself.

Comment: I believe that it knows those localized formats only because humans have entered the format patterns. What isn’t already in the formats for short, medium, long and full formats, it doesn’t know anything about. Not something I know for a fact, but I’d be very surprised …